# How can I pass \xFF as a command line parameter from a Robot Framework test?

Tags: python, linux, robotframework, ipmitool

I am trying to delete an ipmi user, using ipmitool and Linux.
For this, I need to set their name to \xFF.

So I have a command that looks like this:

```bash
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.100 -U admin -P password user set name 4 $(echo -e '\xFF')
```

If I put it into the bash prompt, it works and the user gets deleted.

If I put it into a bash file, that goes like:

```bash
!#/bin/bash
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.100 -U admin -P password user set name 4 $(echo -e '\xFF')
```

And run it via:

```
Test Delete User By File
    ${rc}    ${output}=    Run And Return Rc And Output    ./delete_user.sh
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rc}    ${0}    msg="User not deleted"
```

It also works.

But when I run it this way

```
Test Delete User
    ${rc}    ${output}=    Run And Return Rc And Output    ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.100 -U admin -P password user set name 4 $(echo -e '\\xFF')
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rc}    ${0}    msg="User not deleted"
```

It stops working and ipmitool complains that the arguments are wrong in some way.

And the one thing I have noticed, is that when run in bash the line `echo -e '\xFF'` gives me a `�` symbol.
But when I run it via
`${rc}    ${output}=    Run And Return Rc And Output    echo -e '\xFF'`
I get `ÿ`.

Now, I am running my code remotely on a Linux machine from a Windows system via an SSH tunnel.
There's also someone using Linux to Linux who says it just works without any adjustments.

I did try adding and removing an additional backslash.
I have also tried replacing the `$(echo -e '\xFF')` with `Eval    chr(255)`.
It also gives me `ÿ` and ipmitool says:

> Set User Name command failed (user 4, name ÿ): Invalid data field in request.

I have also tried writing some Python code to this, but it is not working either and has similar problems.

I assume the problem might be with the encoding or the environment, but what can I do to try and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from how `Robot Framework` processes the command line parameter when using `Run And Return Rc And Output`.
You should use `Evaluate` instead of directly inserting `$(echo -e '\\xFF')`

Do the following Robot Framework test case, Make sure to use only a single backslash `(\xFF)` when calling `chr`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test Delete User
    ${char_255} =    Evaluate    chr(255)
    ${rc}    ${output}=    Run And Return Rc And Output    ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.100 -U admin -P password user set name 4 ${char_255}
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rc}    ${0}    msg="User not deleted"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with

```
${rc} ${output} = Run And Return Rc And Output ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.100 -U admin -P password user set name 4 $(bash -c "echo -e '\\xFF'")
```